# Amazon zombie story with a main character who loves Mountain Dew and Doritos

Tags: story-identification, zombie

A couple of years ago in junior high I read a book that I got off of the Amazon book store. It was at the time available exclusively at Amazon. The starting scene talked about the main character (I think his name was Nate) was injured and running from a zombie. He holed up in a store and the zombie started trying to beat its way in.

Nate rummaged around and found a bottle of Mountain Dew and figured the world was ending, the glass was cracking and he was about to be eaten alive by his (former) girlfriend and he would go out with Mountain Dew and Doritos. The glass broke as he opened the bottle of soda and the zombie charged him. Somehow its mouth ended up around the bottle and it drank the soda. The soda made the zombie passive and save Nate. He recorded this with his phone and saved the world.

Some years later he was a billionaire for saving humanity and somehow got involved in a conspiracy to bring about the zombie apocalypse (2.0, this time without the sugar dependency). He spent the story trying to stop this from happening. I think the story was set in 2006 - 2011. One last thing; there was a lot of chaos caused by the issue of what to do with the now harmless zombies. Some wanted to put them in medical facilities and others wanted to just kill them. Some of Nate's friends work as doctors in a similar facility. The bad guys unleashed their new zombies on that facility and only the blonde girl survived.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Zombie Day Care](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17227920-zombie-day-care) by Craig Halloran.

From one of the GoodReads reviews:

> The book begins with the zombies taking over and one man, Nate, accidently discovering that "Fountain Dew" calms them. Thus, Fountain Dew becomes the zombie tamer and Nate becomes a hero. The book then jumps forward about 10 years when the zombies have all been either captured or killed. There are now "zombie day cares" which house zombie children and scientists experiment on them to find a cure. But not everyone is happy that the remainig zombies were saved. Many people still wish them dead.

And another one:

> It starts out during the midst of the zombie take-over with one of the main characters running away from his zombie girlfriend. He can't stand to kill her so by accident he ends up giving her "Fountain Dew" and finds that she stops trying to kill him. With his last battery he tweets the discovery and saves the world. Fast forward a few years and they are trying to find a cure for zombies and controlling them with soft drinks.

I found this almost immediately by searching the web for "zombie story Nate mountain dew soda".

Comment: I cannot believe I got the name right! I usually mix the names of characters up over time. Thanks, now I can reread these.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan You're very welcome! Just edited to include *how* I found it, since Google searching is a surprisingly developed skill.